# Spring set file name external download URL

Tags: spring, redirect

How to set `file name` file from external URL in spring controller?

I want to redirect file download URL

`http//:www.test.com/filedownload/test.txt`

this URL redirect to URL

`http://www.test2.com/filedownload/UniqueFileName.txt`

using

`response.sendRedirect("http://www.test2.com/filedownload/UniqueFileName.txt")`

but in this case file download name is `UniqueFileName.txt`

**want to set reponse header for external URL reponse like below**

```
response.setContentType("application/x-msdownload");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  originalFileName);
```